# Match end and beginning characters or neither

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that would match a character at the beginning and end of the expression or match without the character in either place.  I know I can do this using a `|` and two complete expressions, but is it possible to do so in one expression?

Example text:

```
This is some groovy_[Item]text[/Item]_right here.  And here's some_[Item]more[/Item].
```

Current regex:

```
_?\[Item\]([^\[]+)\[\/Item\]_?
```

For the above, the regex would match `_[Item]text[/Item]_` and `_[Item]more[/Item]`.  However, for the second match, I don't want the leading _, since the trailing _ isn't there.

I could obviously use this regex and it would work:

```
_\[Item\]([^\[]+)\[/Item\]_|\[Item\]([^\[]+)\[/Item\]
```

I just want to know if there's a way to do it without the doubling up of the meat of the expression.

Comment: Is it PCRE, .NET...? You could use a conditional regex.

Comment: @stribizhev: Using .NET, but it should apply generally, right?

Comment: Well, if you need to match exactly the same character, perhaps, a version with a capture group and a back-reference is best. But if you want to match any Unicode space on both ends (say, a regular space before and a hard space after, with `\p{Zs}`), this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?` operator after the space to make it optional, capture it and reference it:

```
(_?)\[Item](.*?)\[/Item]\1
  ^------------ Here ----^
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cX0oE3/2)**

[image]

Comment: But that doesn't require them both (beginning and end) to travel as a pair.

Comment: @zimdanen I've updated the answer, the trick is using a capturing group for the _ and reference it

Comment: Thank you!  That was what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional regex in .NET:

```
( )?\[Item\]([^\[]+)\[/Item\](?(1) )
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(+)%3f%5c%5bItem%5c%5d(%5b%5e%5c%5b%5d%2b)%5c%5b%2fItem%5c%5d(%3f(1)+)&i=This+is+some+groovy+%5bItem%5dtext%5b%2fItem%5d+right+here.++And+here%27s+some+%5bItem%5dmore%5b%2fItem%5d.)

[image]

Here, we match an optional space with `( )?` and then, at the end, if we matched it, we want to also match a space with `(?(1) )`.

If you want to match any Unicode spaces, use `\p{Zs}` instead of just a space.

Comment: Thanks!  This was what I needed.